# get all posts with their associative tags without duplicates

Tags: mysql, join, many-to-many

Two tables. `Post` and `Tag`. Many to Many bi-directional relationship.

```
Post Table              Tag Table             Post_Tag Pivot Table
---------------         ------------          -----------------
id   content            id   name             id_post   id_tag
---------------         ------------          -----------------
 1   hey there           1    php                1        1
                         2    python             1        2
```

I want to get all posts with their tags.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT P.title, T.tag
From Post P
JOIN Tag T
ORDER BY P.id DESC
```

It works, but it gives duplicates:

```
hey there, php
hey there, python
```

Is there a way to group tags together in one row here. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide DDL and sample data so we can't test anything.
Also, it is not clear what is the join predicate, but I think you are looking for [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), something along the lines of (Pseudo code):

```
SELECT P.Title, GROUP_CONCAT(T.Tag SEPARATOR ',') AS Concatenated_Tags
FROM Post P INNER JOIN Tag T ...
GROUP BY P.Title;
```

HTH

Comment: thanks that's what I was looking for, though I need to now somehow make `GROUP_CONCAT` work with doctrine n i'll be all set. thanks for your help